# Evaluating Taylor coefficient of $e^z$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

According to the theory on Taylor polynomials for a complex variable, the $n$-th Taylor coefficient for $e^z$ is given by:

$$
\frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int_{C} \frac{e^z}{z^{n+1}} dz. $$
How do we evaluate this integral over a closed circle of radius $R$? Assume that we do not have any prior idea of power series expansion of $e^z$.

Comment: Can you use the fact that derivative of $e^z$ is $e^z$?

Comment: This is at the point $z=0$.

Comment: I just wanted to know how to evaluate the integral in question by substituting z = R*e^(i*theta)

Comment: residue theorem. Note that, $z=0$ is a pole of order $n+1$.

Comment: is there no formal way of evaluating the resulting integral after the aforementioned substitution where theta varies from 0 to 2pi?